# Querying MySQL InnoDB to find if the Record is in its Buffer Pool

Tags: mysql, innodb, buffer-pool

For us, it is very important to get high response time for our website php script which queries a large database. It is essentially getting user information for the user who visited the page. There may be millions of users in the db.

We would like to not bother using the user data at all if the record is not already in the InnoDB Buffer Pool of the MySQL database, and use information only if present in the above cache.

Is there a way to directly ask Mysql/InnoDB whether the record is in cache?

We thought this might have been addressed by many others when developing high performance web apps.  Is it not common to get data only if can be retrieved in super quick time (for some scenarios at least where response time is very critical) and not otherwise?

Comment: Didn't you ask this somewhere else?

Comment: yes on dba. but there was no reply and we were really in tight situation

Comment: Even it if were implemented, it might take so much time to do the check that the _overall_ system would be slowed down.  I hope you are not using UUIDs; they are terrible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in mechanism to query the MySQL *cache* without causing MySQL to bring the row into memory from disk if it is not already *in memory*.

You *might* want to consider using a caching layer between your website and the database.  Stack Exchange uses [Redis](https://redis.io/); you may want to evaluate that.